# How do I include package installed with Bower?

Tags: bower, modernizr

I've added Modernizr to my project using Bower:

```
# bower install modernizr --save
```

and in looking at what it installs, it's not clear to me which file I need to use in my project.  I would expect a `dist/` folder or perhaps a `modernizr.js` in the root of the project, but there's no such thing.  the files installed are listed below.  is there some missing step that I need to be aware of, or is the file that I want present and if so, which is it?

> bower_components/modernizr bower_components/modernizr/.bower.json
> bower_components/modernizr/.coveralls.yml
> bower_components/modernizr/.editorconfig
> bower_components/modernizr/.gitattributes
> bower_components/modernizr/.gitignore
> bower_components/modernizr/.jscsrc
> bower_components/modernizr/.jshintignore
> bower_components/modernizr/.jshintrc
> bower_components/modernizr/.npmignore
> bower_components/modernizr/.travis.yml
> bower_components/modernizr/appveyor.yml bower_components/modernizr/bin
> bower_components/modernizr/bin/modernizr
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/a
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/a/download.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/ambientlight.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/applicationcache.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/audio
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/audio/loop.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/audio/preload.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/audio/webaudio.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/audio.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/battery
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/battery/lowbattery.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/battery.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/blob.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/canvas
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/canvas/blending.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/canvas/todataurl.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/canvas/winding.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/canvas.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/canvastext.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/contenteditable.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/contextmenu.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/cookies.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/cors.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/crypto
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/crypto/getrandomvalues.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/crypto.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/all.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/animations.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/appearance.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/backdropfilter.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/backgroundblendmode.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/backgroundcliptext.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/backgroundposition-shorthand.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/backgroundposition-xy.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/backgroundrepeat.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/backgroundsize.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/backgroundsizecover.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/borderimage.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/borderradius.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/boxshadow.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/boxsizing.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/calc.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/checked.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/chunit.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/columns.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/cubicbezierrange.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/displayrunin.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/displaytable.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/ellipsis.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/escape.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/exunit.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/filters.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/flexbox.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/flexboxlegacy.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/flexboxtweener.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/flexwrap.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/fontface.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/generatedcontent.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/gradients.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/hairline.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/hsla.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/hyphens.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/invalid.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/lastchild.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/mask.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/mediaqueries.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/multiplebgs.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/nthchild.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/objectfit.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/opacity.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/overflow-scrolling.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/pointerevents.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/positionsticky.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/pseudoanimations.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/pseudotransitions.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/reflections.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/regions.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/remunit.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/resize.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/rgba.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/scrollbars.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/scrollsnappoints.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/shapes.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/siblinggeneral.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/subpixelfont.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/supports.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/target.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/textalignlast.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/textshadow.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/transforms.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/transforms3d.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/transformstylepreserve3d.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/transitions.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/userselect.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/valid.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/vhunit.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/vmaxunit.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/vminunit.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/vwunit.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/will-change.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/css/wrapflow.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/custom-protocol-handler.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/customevent.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/dart.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/dataview-api.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/dom
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/dom/classlist.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/dom/createElement-attrs.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/dom/dataset.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/dom/documentfragment.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/dom/hidden.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/dom/microdata.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/dom/mutationObserver.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/elem
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/elem/bdi.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/elem/datalist.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/elem/details.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/elem/output.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/elem/picture.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/elem/progress-meter.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/elem/ruby.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/elem/template.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/elem/time.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/elem/track.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/elem/unknown.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/emoji.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/es5
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/es5/array.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/es5/date.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/es5/function.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/es5/object.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/es5/specification.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/es5/strictmode.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/es5/string.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/es5/syntax.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/es5/undefined.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/es6
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/es6/array.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/es6/collections.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/es6/contains.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/es6/generators.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/es6/math.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/es6/number.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/es6/object.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/es6/promises.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/es6/string.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/event
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/event/deviceorientation-motion.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/event/oninput.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/eventlistener.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/exif-orientation.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/file
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/file/api.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/file/filesystem.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/flash.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/forcetouch.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/forms
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/forms/capture.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/forms/fileinput.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/forms/fileinputdirectory.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/forms/formattribute.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/forms/inputnumber-l10n.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/forms/placeholder.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/forms/requestautocomplete.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/forms/validation.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/fullscreen-api.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/gamepad.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/geolocation.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/hashchange.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/hiddenscroll.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/history.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/htmlimports.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/ie8compat.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/iframe
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/iframe/sandbox.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/iframe/seamless.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/iframe/srcdoc.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/img
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/img/apng.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/img/crossorigin.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/img/jpeg2000.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/img/jpegxr.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/img/sizes.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/img/srcset.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/img/webp-alpha.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/img/webp-animation.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/img/webp-lossless.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/img/webp.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/indexeddb.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/indexeddbblob.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/input
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/input/formaction.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/input/formenctype.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/input/formmethod.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/input/formtarget.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/input.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/inputsearchevent.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/inputtypes.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/intl.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/json.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/ligatures.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/lists-reversed.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/mathml.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/network
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/network/beacon.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/network/connection.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/network/eventsource.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/network/fetch.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/network/xhr-responsetype-arraybuffer.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/network/xhr-responsetype-blob.js bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/network/xhr-responsetype-document.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/network/xhr-responsetype-json.js bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/network/xhr-responsetype-text.js bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/network/xhr-responsetype.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/network/xhr2.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/notification.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/pagevisibility-api.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/performance.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/pointerevents.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/pointerlock-api.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/postmessage.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/proximity.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/queryselector.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/quota-management-api.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/requestanimationframe.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/script
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/script/async.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/script/defer.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/serviceworker.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/speech
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/speech/speech-recognition.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/speech/speech-synthesis.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/storage
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/storage/localstorage.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/storage/sessionstorage.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/storage/websqldatabase.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/style
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/style/scoped.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/svg
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/svg/asimg.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/svg/clippaths.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/svg/filters.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/svg/foreignobject.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/svg/inline.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/svg/smil.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/svg.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/templatestrings.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/textarea
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/textarea/maxlength.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/touchevents.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/typed-arrays.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/unicode-range.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/unicode.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/url
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/url/bloburls.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/url/data-uri.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/url/parser.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/userdata.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/vibration.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/video
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/video/autoplay.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/video/loop.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/video/preload.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/video.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/vml.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/web-intents.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/webanimations.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/webgl
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/webgl/extensions.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/webgl.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/webrtc
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/webrtc/datachannel.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/webrtc/getusermedia.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/webrtc/peerconnection.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/websockets
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/websockets/binary.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/websockets.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/window
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/window/atob-btoa.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/window/framed.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/window/matchmedia.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/workers
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/workers/blobworkers.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/workers/dataworkers.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/workers/sharedworkers.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/workers/transferables.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/workers/webworkers.js
> bower_components/modernizr/feature-detects/xdomainrequest.js
> bower_components/modernizr/Gruntfile.js bower_components/modernizr/lib
> bower_components/modernizr/lib/.jshintrc
> bower_components/modernizr/lib/build-query.js
> bower_components/modernizr/lib/build.js
> bower_components/modernizr/lib/cli.js
> bower_components/modernizr/lib/config-all.json
> bower_components/modernizr/lib/generate-banner.js
> bower_components/modernizr/lib/metadata.js
> bower_components/modernizr/lib/options.js
> bower_components/modernizr/lib/polyfills.json
> bower_components/modernizr/LICENSE bower_components/modernizr/media
> bower_components/modernizr/media/.gitattributes
> bower_components/modernizr/media/Modernizr 2 Logo vertical big.ai
> bower_components/modernizr/media/Modernizr 2 Logo vertical medium.ai
> bower_components/modernizr/media/Modernizr 2 Logo vertical small.ai
> bower_components/modernizr/media/Modernizr 2 Logo.ai
> bower_components/modernizr/media/Modernizr 2 Logo.eps
> bower_components/modernizr/media/Modernizr 2 Logo.pdf
> bower_components/modernizr/media/Modernizr 2 Logo.png
> bower_components/modernizr/media/Modernizr 2 Logo.svg
> bower_components/modernizr/media/Modernizr-2-Logo-vertical-big.png
> bower_components/modernizr/media/Modernizr-2-Logo-vertical-medium.png
> bower_components/modernizr/media/Modernizr-2-Logo-vertical-small.png
> bower_components/modernizr/package.json
> bower_components/modernizr/readme.md bower_components/modernizr/src
> bower_components/modernizr/src/addTest.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/atRule.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/classes.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/contains.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/createElement.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/cssomPrefixes.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/cssToDOM.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/docElement.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/domPrefixes.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/domToCSS.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/fnBind.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/generate.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/getBody.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/hasEvent.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/hasOwnProp.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/html5printshiv.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/html5shiv.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/injectElementWithStyles.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/inputElem.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/is.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/isSVG.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/load.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/modElem.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/Modernizr.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/ModernizrProto.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/mq.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/mStyle.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/nativeTestProps.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/omPrefixes.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/prefixed.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/prefixedCSS.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/prefixedCSSValue.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/prefixes.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/roundedEquals.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/setClasses.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/slice.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/testAllProps.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/testDOMProps.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/testProp.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/testProps.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/testPropsAll.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/testRunner.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/tests.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/testStyles.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/testXhrType.js
> bower_components/modernizr/src/toStringFn.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test
> bower_components/modernizr/test/.jshintrc
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/iframe.jade
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/integration
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/integration/bools.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/integration/caniuse.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/integration/classes.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/integration/global.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/integration/iframe.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/integration/prefixed-atRule.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/integration/prefixed-autobind.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/integration/prefixed.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/integration/prefixedCSS.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/integration/svg.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/integration.css
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/integration.jade
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/sauce-browsers.json
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/setup.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/addTest.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/atRule.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/classes.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/contains.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/createElement.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/cssomPrefixes.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/cssToDOM.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/docElement.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/domPrefixes.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/domToCSS.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/fnBind.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/generate.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/getBody.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/hasEvent.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/hasOwnProp.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/html5printshiv.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/html5shiv.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/injectElementWithStyles.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/inputElem.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/is.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/load.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/modElem.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/Modernizr.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/ModernizrProto.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/mq.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/mStyle.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/nativeTestProps.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/omPrefixes.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/prefixed.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/prefixedCSS.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/prefixedCSSValue.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/prefixes.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/roundedEquals.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/setClasses.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/slice.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/testAllProps.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/testDOMProps.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/testProp.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/testProps.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/testPropsAll.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/testRunner.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/tests.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/testStyles.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/testXhrType.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/src/toStringFn.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/svgUnit.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/browser/unit.jade
> bower_components/modernizr/test/cleanup.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/img
> bower_components/modernizr/test/img/integration.svg
> bower_components/modernizr/test/img/unit.svg
> bower_components/modernizr/test/js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/js/lib
> bower_components/modernizr/test/js/lib/sinon.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/js/lib/uaparser.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/mocks
> bower_components/modernizr/test/mocks/lib
> bower_components/modernizr/test/mocks/lib/build-query.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/mocks/lib/metadata.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/node
> bower_components/modernizr/test/node/lib
> bower_components/modernizr/test/node/lib/build.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/node/lib/cli.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/node/lib/metadata.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/node/lib/options.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/universal
> bower_components/modernizr/test/universal/lib
> bower_components/modernizr/test/universal/lib/build-query.js
> bower_components/modernizr/test/universal/lib/generate-banner.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

basically, the answer is to run bower install with a properly composed url.  for details see here: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/issues/2073 but if I run:

```
# bower install --save http://modernizr.com/download/?-fontface-backgroundsize-borderimage-borderradius-boxshadow-flexbox-hsla-multiplebgs-opacity-rgba-textshadow-cssanimations-csscolumns-generatedcontent-cssgradients-cssreflections-csstransforms-csstransforms3d-csstransitions-applicationcache-canvas-canvastext-draganddrop-hashchange-history-audio-video-indexeddb-input-inputtypes-localstorage-postmessage-sessionstorage-websockets-websqldatabase-webworkers-geolocation-inlinesvg-smil-svg-svgclippaths-touch-webgl-shiv-mq-cssclasses-addtest-prefixed-teststyles-testprop-testallprops-hasevent-prefixes-domprefixes-load.zip
```

I end up with a:

> bower_components/Modernizr/modernizr.custom.js

that I can include in my .html

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to use it on a webpage, so please correct me if I'm wrong on that count!

I believe you're missing a build step; bower downloads all those files for you, but eventually they all (and any other packages you've installed with bower) need to be "bundled" up into a single .js file that you can embed in your HTML - I believe this is the file you're looking for, and it doesn't yet exist on your computer.

There are many popular build tools, and Bower lists the plugins required for each one [on their website](https://bower.io/docs/tools/). If you're not already using one of these, [grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), [gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) and [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) appear to be the most popular at the moment.

Comment: yes, I mean to use it on a web page, and I did read the docs and figured that I needed to build the package.  Modernizr uses grunt and I ran `grunt` by itself, which ran the tests and did a bunch of stuff, but it still didn't give me a file to include

Comment: In that case I suggest that you install the grunt-bower-concat plugin (npm install grunt-bower-concat --save-dev) and copy their sample to get started: https://github.com/sapegin/grunt-bower-concat#config-example

Comment: are you recommending that I concat all the files in the `src/` directory?

Comment: I'm recommending that you let grunt-bower-concat do its job: it will concatenate all the JS in your bower directory and provide you with a single .js file that you can reference from your HTML via a single <script> tag.

Comment: oh... ok.  I use browserify which is something along those lines.  I will look into it.  thanks mate